# Why is explorer.exe much faster than rsync?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rsync, wsl2

Copying some 150GB from Windows to WSL, doing

```
rsync /mnt/c/big_file big_file -aP
```

rsync manages about 400MB/s, but copying the file on explorer.exe and pasting in \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04, explorer.exe manage to copy the same file at about 900MB/s, why is Explorer more than twice as fast as rsync?

- Windows 10 x64
- WSL 2.0.14.0
- Ubuntu 22.04
- rsync 3.2.7
- explorer.exe version 10.0.19041.3758
- WD Black SN850X NVMe SSD 4TB M.2 7300/6600 MB/s advertised speed

Comment: I think it’s because Rsync is bidirectional even if the files are already copied; it’s always checking the destination. While file explorer just blows away the destination file before copying it. Thus the 900MB/s versus 400MB/s difference.

Comment: Try adding `-u` on the rsync call.

Comment: Rsync verifies the data. So, it reads it into the transfer, and reads it again after the transfer. In default mode, rsync only transfers the difference between source and destination files. In other cases rsync identifies duplicate file by hashsum rather than name and time, rsync has 3 delete methods, delete before, during, after. Before takes considerable time. Rsync is a professional tool with many time consuming options to make it flexible and powerful. I don't thing it will allow no error checking, which Windows probably does by default.

Comment: @brian when copying from local to local almost all the optimisations are disabled and it reverts to not much more than `cp`

Comment: Do you have evidence to support your conclusion. If I specify -c, local or remote, rsync will use crc hashing to identify duplicates rather than name and modify date. If I am making an update  of the debian mirror, if I specify --delete-before, that's what it does. If I specify --delete-before on a local transfer, it does the same.

Comment: Rsync uses deltas (differences between the same file with a different date), whenever it is more expedient, like raw text database tables.

Comment: Copying and pasting is a crap shoot. But it's fast. There is no error checking except that what is in the clipboard is equal to the memory that was clipped. But after it's written, there is no further verification in Windows.

Comment: The XFS file system uses crc32 hashing on every file transaction by default. Rsync is a professional tool that compared to copy and paste in Windows is like a Corvette 350 inch^3 with transmission cooler, turbo charger, 6-speed manual, leather seats, and lingerie in the glove box to a chevette 4-cylinder 3-speed auto.